# What is JavaScriptExecutor in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is JavaScript Executor in Selenium WebDriver?

What is the use of it and how can we use this in Selenium WebDriver?

An example would be appreciated.

Comment: They actually misspelled JavaScript: *[JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### JavascriptExecutor

[**JavascriptExecutor**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) is the *Selenium* interface which is being implemented by all the following classes:

- `FirefoxDriver`
- `ChromeDriver`
- `InternetExplorerDriver`
- `EdgeDriver`
- `OperaDriver`
- `SafariDriver`
- `RemoteWebDriver`
- `EventFiringWebDriver`
- `HtmlUnitDriver`

While you execute your *Selenium* script at times because of cross domain policies browsers enforce your script execution may fail unexpectedly and without adequate error logging. This is particularly pertinent when creating your own XHR request or when trying to access another frame.

You will find a detailed discussion in [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from)

JavascriptExecutor interface provides two methods as follows:

- [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-): This method executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function. Within the script you need to use `document` to refer to the current document. Note that local variables will not be available once the script has finished executing, though global variables will persist.
- [**`executeAsyncScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-): This method executes an asynchronous piece of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. Unlike executing synchronous JavaScript, scripts executed with this method must explicitly signal they are finished by invoking the provided callback. This callback is always injected into the executed function as the last argument.

---

### Example

A couple of examples:

- [Using JS to enter text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453087/using-js-to-enter-text-but-if-i-input-text-in-one-text-box-the-value-already-e)

  ```
  String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')"
  ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(js, element);
  ```
- [Double click through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981080/how-to-make-mouse-double-click-in-javascript)

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(myElem, posX, posY).perform();
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(jsDoubleClick, myElem, posX, posY);
  ```
- [Sending variable character strings through executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596978/selenium-how-to-send-variable-character-strings-through-executescript)

  ```
  String myValue = "80120804076";
  WebElement pesel = driver.findElement(fldPesel);
  jse.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + myValue + "';", pesel);
  ```

---

### Reference

You also can find a couple of detailed discussions about the **arguments** in:

- [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro)

---

### tl;dr

[Cross-domain policy file specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html)

Answer (score 3):

The long and short answer is:

It's a Selenium interface which directly lets you interact with the HTML [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) of the webpage. It does so by executing JavaScript expressions using the following syntax:

`(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("JavaScript_EXPRESSION_HERE", ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS);`

JavascriptExecutor provides a way to automate a user interaction even when the page is not essentially loaded completely or elements are placed in a way that the direct interaction is blocked.

This, however, is also the disadvantage too, if you want to automate a webpage as if a real user experience. That said, although it is a really powerful option, but we should try not to use JavaScript Executor unless there isn't any standard way of doing it via Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse *[Interface JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)* to get more information:

> Indicates that a driver can execute JavaScript, providing access to
> the mechanism to do so. Because of cross domain policies browsers
> enforce your script execution may fail unexpectedly and without
> adequate error messaging. This is particularly pertinent when creating
> your own XHR request or when trying to access another frame. Most
> times when troubleshooting failure it's best to view the browser's
> console after executing the WebDriver request.

Basically, JavaScript Executor allows you to execute JavaScript code from Selenium WebDriver.

Example:
Scrolling to element with JavaScript.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("test"));
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptExecutor is an interface that is used to execute JavaScript code through Selenium WebDriver. It provides two methods, “executescript” & “executeAsyncScript”:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1200)");
```

Comment: Well, they actually misspelled JavaScript: [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptExecutor is an Interface that helps to execute JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver. Sometimes we face a lot of issues when performing actions on web elements. Then this concept comes into the picture. Required package:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Methods of JavaScriptExecutor:

1. executeAsyncScript:

   *executeAsyncScript(java.lang.String script, java.lang.Object… args)*

Execute an asynchronous piece of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window.

2. executeScript:

   *executeScript(java.lang.String script, java.lang.Object… args)*

Executes JavaScript with below Syntax:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(Script,Arguments);
```

Please refer to the [link](https://biswasarpita.medium.com/javascriptexecutor-in-selenium-webdriver-with-example-4fe356f41b62) for more details. How to apply this interface based on different situations discussed here.

Comment: Well, they actually misspelled JavaScript: [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Answer (score -1):

My solution in Selenium 3:

```
 driver.execute_script("window.open()")
```