# How to extract the text present in DOM using Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get text present in Dom structure but I could't get it, I have used `getText();` and `getAttribute();` but not getting I have used value,inner html,outer html,text and so on which has to be mention in getAttribute();but unable to get that text could any one help me to get from it.

```
<label class="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="ml+4gvbuEG8Y3bBbAEbQvA==" name="selectedemployees" class="checkall">Alberta              Weekly1             
</label>
```

I want to get "Alberta Weekly1" text in my console

[image]

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImL7K.png)

Comment: Post the code, including how you locate the element, and explain what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Are you trying to get the checkbox value ? True/False, Also let us know the language (Java/C#/ Python)

Comment: no i just want text highlighted with RED colour

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **Alberta Weekly1** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and as the desired node is a *text node* you can use [`executeScript()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) method along with either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath 1*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[./input[@class='checkall' and @name='selectedemployees']]")))).toString());
  ```
- *xpath 2*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label/input[@class='checkall' and @name='selectedemployees']/..")))).toString());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Text `Alberta Weekly1` You need to induce `WebDriverWait` And `visibilityOfElementLocated()` And use the below `XPATH` Option.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
String textval=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[./input[@name='selectedemployees']]"))).getText(); 
System.out.println(textval);
```

Comment: i'am getting only Alberta Weekly1 text, i have to get all text mentioned in unique way

Comment: @phanikumar : Your requirement was to get the text `Alberta Weekly1` .If you want to fetch all the text you need to post DOM element for all the text you are after?

Comment: you are right but the xpath is written for all elements //label[./input[@name='selectedemployees']]  .not for single element

Comment: So when you run that code what text you are getting?

Comment: Check the following xpath : `//label[./input[@name='selectedemployees' and @class='checkall']]`

Comment: plz check 'Console output' image on my query i have posted, i just want to get unique mentioned in application image, i have to get all check boxes names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below given xpath as well.

```
//label//child::input[@class='checkall' and @name='selectedemployees']
```