# How to Pass Variables into a javascriptexecutor script

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# and Selenium to navigate a site and was wondering how to pass variables into my JavaScriptExecutor command. If I write it like this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webdriver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementByID('text box1').value = 'hello'");
```

That works fine but when I try to pass it variables it says they are not defined:

```
var elementID = "text box1"
var fieldValue = "hello"
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webdriver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementByID(elementID).value = fieldValue");
```

Comment: you can use arguments.  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was needing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass variables into a [*JavaScriptExecutor*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro) command you can use the following solution:

```
var elementID = "text box1"
var fieldValue = "hello"
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webdriver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('" + elementID + "').value ='" + fieldValue + "'");
```

> PS: It's **`document.getElementById()`** and not `document.getElementByID()`. Check the case of `Id`.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to send variable character strings through executeScript()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596978/selenium-how-to-send-variable-character-strings-through-executescript/49597079#49597079)
- [What does arguments[0] and arguments[1] mean when using executeScript method from JavascriptExecutor interface through Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-arguments0-and-arguments1-mean-when-using-executescript-method-fro/49873090#49873090)